# Unable to create bosh release

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry, bosh-deployer, cf-bosh

I am unable to create a bosh release from `learn-bosh-release` tutorial given [here](https://mariash.github.io/learn-bosh/#introduction)

Getting the following error:

```
vagrant@bosh-lite:~/workspace/learn-bosh-release$ bosh create release
Syncing blobs...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:349:in `symlink': Protocol error - (/home/vagrant/workspace/learn-bosh-release/.blobs/c8a000f75b6a6f60d9fb727f8076ec9171e14c20, /home/vagrant/workspace/learn-bosh-release/blobs/ruby/bundler-1.6.3.gem) (Errno::EPROTO)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:349:in `block in ln_s'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1568:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:347:in `ln_s'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/blob_manager.rb:344:in `install_blob'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/blob_manager.rb:235:in `block in process_index'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/blob_manager.rb:214:in `each_pair'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/blob_manager.rb:214:in `process_index'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/blob_manager.rb:157:in `sync'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/commands/release/create_release.rb:146:in `dirty_blob_check'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/commands/release/create_release.rb:82:in `create_from_spec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/commands/release/create_release.rb:51:in `create'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/command_handler.rb:57:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/lib/cli/runner.rb:59:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/bosh_cli-1.3262.26.0/bin/bosh:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/bosh:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/bosh:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got rid of the issue.

Was using Git-bash over Windows 10 for working with bosh and had setup a bosh-lite VM using Vagrant. Issue with `symlink - Protocol Error` was due to Git-bash not having administrative privileges.

Resolution :

- Start `git-bash` or `cmd` as an Administrator on Windows
- `vagrant ssh` into the bosh-lite vm
- Now `bosh create release` was able to write a manifest file successfully